# javascript to check if file extension is found in list

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript to check if a pdf or doc extension is found in the item of a list. If it is, I want to remove that element. Is there an easy way to make this work. I can detect if its there. It returns true, but not sure how to select that specific element.

```js
if (document.querySelector("#myList").innerHTML.includes(".pdf") || (".doc")) {
  //find and remove item

}
```

```html
<div id="myList">
<div class="style">
  <img class="myIm" src="/v2l/le/1196xx/discussions/posts/26adsd89/ViewAttachment?fileId=273383625">
  <div class="">photoTest.jpg</div>
</div>
<div class="style">
  <img class="myImg-style" src="/v2l/le/11961xx/discussions/posts/26ss489/ViewAttachment?fileId=27773626">
  <div class="">dog.png</div>
</div>
<div class="style">
  <img class="myImg-style" src="/v2l/common/viewFile.v2lfile/Im/638054389092471030/testpde.pdf?ou=11961xxx&amp;fid=ZTZlMDllZGEtMWM0Yi00ZWRlLWI5ODAtMjhhNWRmYjc1MzBmO0dyYXBoaWNEZXNpZ25fT25saW5lX0NvdXJzZU91dGxpbmUucGRmOzU1ODY0MDE">
  <div class="">testpde.pdf</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `somestring.includes(".pdf") || (".doc")` is a logic error. Suggest combining using regex: `somestring.match(/\.(pdf|doc)/)`

Comment: And where is your *"unordered list"*? Isn't this `div class=""` useless?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan `.match()` returns null when there isn't a match. It'll work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove the elements if a child contains a specific string (`.pdf` or `.doc`) use:

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);

// Utility functions:

const isDocument = (fileName) => /\.(pdf|doc)$/.test(fileName);

// Task: Remove element if child text is document

els(".style").forEach(elStyle => {
  const elFile = el("div", elStyle);
  const text = elFile.textContent.trim();
  isDocument(text) && elFile.remove();
});
```

```html
<div id="myList">
  <div class="style">
    <img class="myIm" src="/v2l/le/1196xx/discussions/posts/26adsd89/ViewAttachment?fileId=273383625">
    <div class="">photoTest.jpg</div>
  </div>
  <div class="style">
    <img class="myImg-style" src="/v2l/le/11961xx/discussions/posts/26ss489/ViewAttachment?fileId=27773626">
    <div class="">dog.png</div>
  </div>
  <div class="style">
    <img class="myImg-style" src="/v2l/common/viewFile.v2lfile/Im/638054389092471030/testpde.pdf?ou=11961xxx&amp;fid=ZTZlMDllZGEtMWM0Yi00ZWRlLWI5ODAtMjhhNWRmYjc1MzBmO0dyYXBoaWNEZXNpZ25fT25saW5lX0NvdXJzZU91dGxpbmUucGRmOzU1ODY0MDE">
    <div class="">testpde.pdf</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additional resource:

- [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Answer (score -1):

```
function hasExtOfList(src, list) {
   return list.some(ext => src.includes(ext))
}

hasExtOfList(
  document.querySelector("#myList").innerHTML,
  [".pdf", ".doc"]
)
```

---

JS does have `Set`, but there's no point to use it as you need to iterate anyways, everything in JS is ordered

Comment: so this would return the items that have a pdf or doc extension?

Comment: need it to return items that dont have those extensions...or remove the ones that do